# How do I access files inside a Wubi virtual ext4 Ubuntu partition from within Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, wubi, ext4

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 using Wubi on a PC that has Windows XP and Windows 7 installed. I was working in it for a while and everything is just fine.

However, when I booted back into Windows 7, I couldn't figure out a way to access the files I had created or downloaded into the Ubuntu partition. They're in a virtual disk called `root.disk` in my `C:\ubuntu\disks`.

Is there a way I can mount this vhd into Windows or at least browse the contents and extract what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Also check out "Explore2FS", "ext2explore" and "ext2IFS". One of those also supports writing to an "ext2/3"partition (even if it is a Wubi virtual disk (.disk)). So far, I have not come across one that supports writing to an "ext4" partition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [Ext2Read](http://ext2read.blogspot.com/)?

> Ext2Read is an explorer like utility to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It now supports Linux LVM2. It can be used to view and copy files and folders. It can recursively copy entire folders. It can also be used to view and copy disk and file system images.